# How do traits classes work and what do they do?

Tags: c++, traits

I'm reading Scott Meyers' [*Effective C++*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321334876). He is talking about traits classes, I understood that I need them to determine the type of the object during compilation time, but I can't understand his explanation about what these classes actually do? (from technical point of view)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Perhaps you’re expecting some kind of magic that makes type traits work. In that case, be disappointed – there is no magic. Type traits are *manually* defined for each type. For example, consider `iterator_traits`, which provides typedefs (e.g. `value_type`) for iterators.

Using them, you can write

```
iterator_traits<vector<int>::iterator>::value_type x;
iterator_traits<int*>::value_type y;
// `x` and `y` have type int.
```

But to make this work, there is actually an *explicit definition* somewhere in the `<iterator>` header, which reads something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct iterator_traits<T*> {
    typedef T value_type;
    // …
};
```

This is a *partial specialization* of the `iterator_traits` type for types of the form `T*`, i.e. pointers of some generic type.

In the same vein, `iterator_traits` are specialized for other iterators, e.g. `typename vector<T>::iterator`.

Comment: +1 for no magic. Even though, aren't there some traits (e.g in C++0x standard library) that can't be reliably defined using only the language, and that need special "magical" help from the compiler to work?

Comment: @UncleBens: I don’t know which traits C++0x defines but I’m certain that no such traits exist before C++0x.

Comment: Isn't *now* a kind of magic working within [`std::underlying_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type)?

Comment: @Wolf C++11 added a few traits which cannot be implemented on the user side, they need compiler support. And, yes, `std::underlying_type` is one of them.

Comment: When I read your `there is no magic`, I was wondering whether this detail would matter for this question...

Comment: @Wolf Well the answer was written *long* before C++11 came out.

Answer (score 44):

Traits classes do *not* determine the type of the object. Instead, they provide additional information about a type, typically by defining typedefs or constants inside the trait.