# What is the template trait classes in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, traits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do traits classes work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979766/how-do-traits-classes-work)

Can anyone please explain template trait classes in C++? I tried to read through some of the books but I just can't get my head around it.

Comment: What is it you don't understand about traits?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979766/how-do-traits-classes-work

Comment: Why and how to use them? For me it looks like template specialization and trait classes are similar.

Comment: @polapts: that's because trait classes are specialized templates. Not all template specializations are trait classes, though.