# What is the difference between a trait and a policy?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, type-traits, policy-based-design

I have a class whose behavior I am trying to configure.

```
template<int ModeT, bool IsAsync, bool IsReentrant> ServerTraits;
```

Then later on I have my server object itself:

```
template<typename TraitsT>
class Server {…};
```

My question is for my usage above is my naming misnamed? Is my templated parameter actually a policy instead of a trait?

When is a templated argument a trait versus a policy?

Comment: A trait tends to be a property that is derived from a class, rather than given to it.

Comment: If you are unsure there's plenty of information on traits to be found on the net: [An introduction to C++ Traits](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442), [How do traits classes work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979766/how-do-traits-classes-work), [Traits: a new and useful template technique](http://www.cantrip.org/traits.html)

Comment: So what I have is actually a Policy and not a Traits?

Comment: Yes, looks more like a policy

Comment: @Tony, thanks for the links as they are good intro to traits.

Comment: This is a good candidate for c++FAQ tag

Answer (score 88, accepted):

### Policies

Policies are classes (or class templates) to **inject behavior** into a parent class, typically through inheritance. Through decomposing a parent interface into orthogonal (independent) dimensions, policy classes form the building blocks of more complex interfaces. An often seen pattern is to supply policies as user-definable template (or template-template) parameters with a library-supplied default. An example from the Standard Library are the Allocators, which are policy template parameters of all STL containers

```
template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> class vector;
```

Here, the `Allocator` template parameter (which itself is also a class template!) injects the memory allocation and deallocation policy into the parent class `std::vector`. If the user does not supply an allocator, the default `std::allocator<T>` is used.

As is typical in template-based polymporphism, the interface requirements on policy classes are **implicit and semantic** (based on valid expressions) rather than explicit and syntactic (based on the definition of virtual member functions).

Note that the more recent unordered associative containers, have more than one policy. In addition to the usual `Allocator` template parameter, they also take a `Hash` policy that defaults to `std::hash<Key>` function object. This allows users of unordered containers to configure them along multiple orthogonal dimensions (memory allocation and hashing).

### Traits

Traits are class templates to **extract properties** from a generic type. There are two kind of traits: single-valued traits and multiple-valued traits. Examples of single-valued traits are the ones from the header `<type_traits>`

```
template< class T >
struct is_integral
{
    static const bool value /* = true if T is integral, false otherwise */;
    typedef std::integral_constant<bool, value> type;
};
```

Single-valued traits are often used in **template-metaprogramming** and SFINAE tricks to overload a function template based on a type condition.

Examples of multi-valued traits are the iterator_traits and allocator_traits from the headers `<iterator>` and `<memory>`, respectively. Since traits are class templates, they can be specialized. Below an example of the specialization of `iterator_traits` for `T*`

```
template<T>
struct iterator_traits<T*>
{
    using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type        = T;
    using pointer           = T*;
    using reference         = T&;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
};
```

The expression `std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type` makes it possible to make generic code for full-fledged iterator classes usable even for raw pointers (since raw pointers don't have a member `value_type`).

### Interaction between policies and traits

When writing your own generic libraries, it is important to think about ways users can specialize your own class templates. One has to be careful, however, not to let users fall victim to the **One Definition Rule** by using specializations of traits to inject rather than to extract behavior. To paraphrase this [old post](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2002/04/28906.php) by Andrei Alexandrescu

> The fundamental problem is that code that doesn't see the specialized
>   version of a trait  will still compile, is likely to link, and
>   sometimes might even run. This is because in the absence of the
>   explicit specialization, the non-specialized template kicks in, likely
>   implementing a generic behavior that works for your special case as
>   well. Consequently, if not all the code in an application sees the
>   same definition of a trait, the ODR is violated.

The C++11 `std::allocator_traits` avoids these pitfalls by enforcing that all STL containers can only extract properties from their `Allocator` policies through `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>`. If users choose not to or forget to supply some of the required policy members, the traits class can step in and supply default values for those missing members. Because `allocator_traits` itself cannot be specialized, users always have to pass a fully defined allocator policy in order to customize their containers memory allocation, and no silent ODR violations can occur.

Note that as a library-writer, one can still specialize traits class templates (as the STL does in `iterator_traits<T*>`), but it is good practice to pass all user-defined specializations through policy classes into multi-valued traits that can extract the specialized behavior (as the STL does in `allocator_traits<A>`).

**UPDATE**: The ODR problems of user-defined specializations of traits classes happen mainly when traits are used as **global class templates** and you cannot guarantee that all future users will see all other user-defined specializations. Policies are **local template parameters** and contain all the relevant definitions, allowing them to be user-defined without interference in other code. Local template parameters that only contain type and constants -but no behaviorally functions- might still be called "traits" but they would not be visible to other code like the `std::iterator_traits` and `std::allocator_traits`.

Comment: Still to press the question further, I found the following in the original Meyers paper (http://www.cantrip.org/traits.html) "Traits class:
A class used in place of template parameters. As a class, it aggregates useful types and constants; as a template, it provides an avenue for that "extra level of indirection" that solves all software problems". In my original example, I have an aggregation of policies. Does that make it a traits then? But it is still injecting behavior thus giving it a policy characteristic! It seems to be both. Argh I'm still having problems what to call it. Input?

Comment: @NateDoromal A policy can also contain types and constants, but typically is more behaviorally oriented. Another difference is that policies are passed as template parameters, while traits are global classes (this is the reason that it is a bad idea for users to specialize them, because you never know which other users will see which specializations, leading to the mentioned ODR problems). Because you pass `TraitsT` as a parameter, I would call your `TraitsT` a Policy. If you also have a global class to extract the various types and functions, then that would be a  multi-valued traits class.

Comment: @NateDoromal Also remember that the concepts of traits and polices were developed 15+ years ago. Since then, substantial experience with them has been gained. The ODR problems that Alexandrescu identified have been avoided in the recent STL allocator and iterator traits. The nomenclature is not mandated by the Standard, so keep in mind the semantic differences rather than the oldfashioned behavior vs type/constant distinction. Policies: injection, local, customizable; Traits: extraction, global, fixed (to avoid ODR).

Answer (score 25):

I think you will find the best possible answer to your question in **[this book by Andrei Alexandrescu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design)**. Here, I will try to give just a short overview. Hopefully it will help.

---

A **traits class** is class that is usually intended to be a meta-function associating types to other types or to constant values to provide a characterization of those types. In other words, it is a way to model *properties of types*. The mechanism normally exploits templates and template specialization to define the association:

```
template<typename T>
struct my_trait
{
    typedef T& reference_type;
    static const bool isReference = false;
    // ... (possibly more properties here)
};

template<>
struct my_trait<T&>
{
    typedef T& reference_type;
    static const bool isReference = true;
    // ... (possibly more properties here)
};
```

The trait metafunction `my_trait<>` above associates the reference type `T&` and the constant Boolean value `false` to all types `T` which are *not* themselves references; on the other hand, it associates the reference type `T&` and the constant Boolean value `true` to all types `T` that *are* references.

So for instance:

```
int  -> reference_type = int&
        isReference = false

int& -> reference_type = int&
        isReference = true
```

In code, we could assert the above as follows (all the four lines below will compile, meaning that the condition expressed in the first argument to `static_assert()` is satisfied):

```
static_assert(!(my_trait<int>::isReference), "Error!");
static_assert(  my_trait<int&>::isReference, "Error!");
static_assert(
    std::is_same<typename my_trait<int>::reference_type, int&>::value, 
    "Error!"
     );
static_assert(
    std::is_same<typename my_trait<int&>::reference_type, int&>::value, 
    "Err!"
    );
```

Here you could see I made use of the standard `std::is_same<>` template, which is itself a meta-function that accepts *two*, rather than one, type argument. Things can get arbitrarily complicated here.

Although `std::is_same<>` is part of the `type_traits` header, some consider a class template to be a type traits class only if it acts as a meta-predicate (thus, accepting *one* template parameter). To the best of my knowledge, however, the terminology is not clearly defined.

For an example of usage of a traits class in the C++ Standard Library, have a look at how the Input/Output Library and the String Library are designed.

---

A **policy** is something slightly different (actually, pretty different). It is normally meant to be a class that specifies what the behavior of another, generic class should be regarding certain operations that could be potentially realized in several different ways (and whose implementation is, therefore, left up to the policy class).

For instance, a generic smart pointer class could be designed as a template class that accepts a policy as a template parameter for deciding how to handle ref-counting - this is just a hypothetical, overly simplistic, and illustrative example, so please try to abstract from this concrete code and focus on the *mechanism*.

That would allow the designer of the smart pointer to make no hard-coded commitment as to whether or not modifications of the reference counter shall be done in a thread-safe manner:

```
template<typename T, typename P>
class smart_ptr : protected P
{
public:
    // ... 
    smart_ptr(smart_ptr const& sp)
        :
        p(sp.p),
        refcount(sp.refcount)
    {
        P::add_ref(refcount);
    }
    // ...
private:
    T* p;
    int* refcount;
};
```

In a multi-threaded context, a client could use an instantiation of the smart pointer template with a policy that realizes thread-safe increments and decrements of the reference counter (Windows platformed assumed here):

```
class mt_refcount_policy
{
protected:
    add_ref(int* refcount) { ::InterlockedIncrement(refcount); }
    release(int* refcount) { ::InterlockedDecrement(refcount); }
};

template<typename T>
using my_smart_ptr = smart_ptr<T, mt_refcount_policy>;
```

In a single-threaded environment, on the other hand, a client could instantiate the smart pointer template with a policy class that simply increases and decreases the counter's value:

```
class st_refcount_policy
{
protected:
    add_ref(int* refcount) { (*refcount)++; }
    release(int* refcount) { (*refcount)--; }
};

template<typename T>
using my_smart_ptr = smart_ptr<T, st_refcount_policy>;
```

This way, the library designer has provided a flexible solution that is capable of offering the best compromise between performance and safety (*"You don't pay for what you don't use"*).

Comment: The typedef of `reference_type` is incorrect for `my_traits<T&>`, it should be `typedef T& reference_type;`.

Comment: @SylvainDefresne: Right, fixed it. Thank you

Comment: you can actually use a policy for deletion with smart pointers.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ModeT, IsReentrant, and IsAsync to control the behaviour of the Server, then it's a policy.

Alternatively, if you are want a way to describe the characteristics of the server to another object, then you could define a traits class like so:

```
template <typename ServerType>
class ServerTraits;

template<>
class ServerTraits<Server>
{
    enum { ModeT = SomeNamespace::MODE_NORMAL };
    static const bool IsReentrant = true;
    static const bool IsAsync = true;
}
```

Comment: nice, that actually boils down the accepted answer to the given example :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of examples to clarify Alex Chamberlain's comment:

A common example of a trait class is std::iterator_traits. Let's say we have some template class C with a member function which takes two iterators, iterates over the values, and accumulates the result in some way. We want the accumulation strategy to be defined as part of the template too, but will use a policy rather than a trait to achieve that.

```
template <typename Iterator, typename AccumulationPolicy>
class C{
    void foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end){
        AccumulationPolicy::Accumulator accumulator;
        for(Iterator i = begin; i != end; ++i){
            std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type value = *i;
            accumulator.add(value);
        }
    }
};
```

The policy is passed in to our template class, while the trait is derived from the template parameter. So what you have is more akin to a policy. There are situations where traits are more appropriate, and where policies are more appropriate, and often the same effect can be achieved with either method leading to some debate about which is most expressive.

Answer (score 0):

**Policies** are passed through the API by the user to actively choose which code paths should be followed inside a certain interface.

**Traits** on the other hand are used by the library author to select certain overloads based on what the user passes into the API.

Traits are a way of the library author reacting to the user input, whereas policies are a way for the user to actively influence the library behaviour.